# About the list view in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce, could I get back the campaign Id from contact list view?

If yes, how could I do that. I know that list view is a metadata, but not an object. How can I query the campaign Id field from metadata.

Urgent Please help. I have search for webs for few days but still cannot figure out the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A contact can belong to multiple campaigns, so there's no single campaign field on the Contact record that you could include in the List View layout.

There's nothing to stop you creating it though.  Create a field called "Campaign" as a lookup to Campaigns and populate it for the Contacts. (This would have to be done manually or using Apex)  Then include it in the List View layout.